# Killing the mysqld process

Tags: sql, database, sql-update, mysql

I have a table with ~800k rows. I ran an `update users set hash = SHA1(CONCAT({about eight fields})) where 1;`

Now I have a hung Sequel Pro process and I'm not sure about the `mysqld` process.

This is two questions:

1. What harm can possibly come from killing these programs? I'm working on a separate database, so no damage should come to other databases on the system, right?
2. Assume you had to update a table like this. What would be a quicker / more reliable method of updating **without writing a separate script**.

I just checked with phpMyAdmin and it *appears* as though the query is complete. I still have Sequel Pro using 100% of both my cores though...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using InnoDB, which is backed by a transaction log for recovery and rollback purposes, then you can get away with a lot, especially in a non-production environment.

The easiest way to terminate a renegade query is to use the MySQL shell as the root user:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

This will give you a list of the current connections and a process ID for each one. To terminate any given query, such as number 19, use:

```
KILL 19;
```

Usually this will undo and roll back the query. In some cases this is not sufficient and you may have to force-quit the MySQL server process with `kill -9`. Under most circumstances you should be able to restart the server right away, and the DB will be in the last fully committed state.

Answer (score 1):

To get the thread IDs (it'll show the query alongside):

```
mysqladmin proc
```

To safely kill the query thread:

```
mysqladmin kill [id]
```

You'll end up with a partially updated table unless you use innodb, but you should be fine. [Details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/kill.html):

> During UPDATE or DELETE operations,
>   the kill flag is checked after each
>   block read and after each updated or
>   deleted row. If the kill flag is set,
>   the statement is aborted. Note that if
>   you are not using transactions, the
>   changes are not rolled back.

As for your second question, there is no better way to update a table if one is not allowed to write a separate script (to, say, throttle the updates).