# MySQL - Can aborting a query with Ctrl-C harm the table?

Tags: mysql, database, terminal

Some of my queries were taking way too long, including some `alter table` queries, so I pressed **Ctrl-c** to abort them and continue with other matters.

One that I aborted was `alter table labs modify ID int(11) first`.

Now quite simple queries like `alter table labs drop column ID` are taking forever. I've been waiting for over 25 minutes. There *are* millions of records, but I've run similar `alter table` queries on the same table that only take a few seconds.

Can aborting queries harm the column that the query was operating on? If so, how can I recover from the problem?

---

**Update**: I *am* nuking a primary-key column. Could that have something to do with the insanely long running time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the transaction wasn't completed, no. MySQL does `ALTER TABLE` by creating a new table and then updates the reference to the old table. You shouldn't have altered your original table if you interrupted the original `ALTER TABLE` query.

[Source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html#idm140269597023088).

Comment: Okay, that's comforting. Would you have any idea why the `alter table labs drop column ID` is taking forever though? It's still running.

Comment: @Dylan a good number of reasons. Perhaps that column is indexed? Or is foreign-keyed, with triggers in other tables that react to being deleted? Maybe I/O is blocked by something else, compared to when you ran the other `alter` in the past?

Comment: The column is primary-keyed, would that cause lots of delay? It isn't foreign-keyed.

Comment: `alter table` will typically take a *long time* if there are several-to-many (large) indexes to re-create. Do you have *several-to-many* indexes on the table?

Comment: I have to admit I've never nuked a primary-key column before! That seems like a bad idea, not sure of the performance implications there. I'll have to let someone else chime in though

Comment: Oh, if the column is the `PRIMARY KEY` then I would suspect the `ALTER TABLE` will have some trouble as there is no longer an index to assist in the re-building of the table. It'd fall into a table scan or sorts which is rather painful.

Comment: @Marcus I only have an index on one column, so it definitely sounds like a primary key issue. I can't even move it to be the first column without insanely long running times.

Comment: With a million rows, dropping a key will probably take a while.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Not necessarily.

If you're using InnoDB, which is backed by a transaction log for recovery and rollback purposes, then you can get away with a lot, especially in a non-production environment.

The easiest way to terminate a renegade query is to use the MySQL shell as the root user:

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
```

This will give you a list of the current connections and a process ID for each one. To terminate any given query, such as number 19, use:

```
KILL 19;
```

Usually this will undo and roll back the query. In some cases this is not sufficient and you may have to force-quit the MySQL server process with kill -9. Under most circumstances you should be able to restart the server right away, and the DB will be in the last fully committed state.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3442027/4148092

Comment: Oops. Sorry I'll watch out for that next time :)